# why does wget/curl/urllib2 of python gives a different html page than view source in browser

Tags: html, curl, urllib2, wget

I am trying to fetch some data from a site using urllib2 and I get different HTML page than what I see when I click on view source (some elements are swapped in divs, some elements in divs are totally not there etc)

example:
try this python script

```
import urllib2

markup = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_trksid=p5197.m570.l1313&_nkw=harry+potter&_sacat=0&_from=R40").read()
```

and some samples tags from the above are (**this is wrong**, this is not how data is shown on page, checked it with firebug too)

```
<div class="catsgroup">
    <div class="cat-t"><a href="http://www.ebay.com/sch/Books-/267/i.html?_from=R40&amp;_nkw=harry+potter">Books</a><span class="cnt">&nbsp;(7,777)</span></div>
    <div class="cat-c">
        <div class="default">
            <div class="cat-link"><a href="http://www.ebay.com/sch/Children-Young-Adults-/279/i.html?_from=R40&amp;_nkw=harry+potter">Children &amp; Young Adults</a><span class="cnt">&nbsp;(1,999)</span></div> 
            <div class="cat-link"><a href="http://www.ebay.com/sch/Nonfiction-/378/i.html?_from=R40&amp;_nkw=harry+potter">Nonfiction</a><span class="cnt">&nbsp;(2,414)</span></div> 
            <div class="cat-link"><a href="http://www.ebay.com/sch/Fiction-Literature-/377/i.html?_from=R40&amp;_nkw=harry+potter">Fiction &amp; Literature</a><span class="cnt">&nbsp;(1,461)</span></div> 
            **<div class="cat-link"><a href="http://www.ebay.com/sch/Antiquarian-Collectible-/29223/i.html?_from=R40&amp;_nkw=harry+potter">Antiquarian &amp; Collectible</a><span class="cnt">&nbsp;(508)</span></div>**
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The last line with the ** doesn't belong to that tag in view source, but it does in **curl/wget/urllib2**

same snippet from view source (**This is actually how data is viewed on page**)

```
<div class="catsgroup">
    <div class="cat-t"><a href="http://www.ebay.com/sch/Books-/267/i.html?_from=R40&amp;_nkw=harry+potter">Books</a><span class="cnt">&nbsp;(4,358)</span></div>
    <div class="cat-c">
        <div class="default">
            <div class="cat-link"><a href="http://www.ebay.com/sch/Children-Young-Adults-/279/i.html?_from=R40&amp;_nkw=harry+potter">Children &amp; Young Adults</a><span class="cnt">&nbsp;(1,334)</span></div> 
            <div class="cat-link"><a href="http://www.ebay.com/sch/Nonfiction-/378/i.html?_from=R40&amp;_nkw=harry+potter">Nonfiction</a><span class="cnt">&nbsp;(1,298)</span></div> 
            <div class="cat-link"><a href="http://www.ebay.com/sch/Fiction-Literature-/377/i.html?_from=R40&amp;_nkw=harry+potter">Fiction &amp; Literature</a><span class="cnt">&nbsp;(710)</span></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help with whats going wrong here and how to get correct html as shown in view source is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you logged in with your Ebay account in your browser?

Comment: nope. I am not logged in.

Comment: Then it has to be the User Agent. At least with Wget you should be able to send to the server the same User Agent than your browser.